# Why do floats change the \mark?

Tags: floats, header-footer

The presence of floats appears to disrupt the setting of `\mark`s, so that `\topmark` ends up with the wrong value.

For example, consider this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight 50mm
\textwidth 50mm

\makeatletter \def\@oddhead{[\topmark/\firstmark/\botmark]} \makeatother

\def\block#1{\textbf{#1}\mark{#1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Foo bar baz.\par}

\begin{document}

\block a
\block b
\block c
\block d
%\begin{figure}\hrule width 1pt height 20mm depth 0pt \end{figure}
\block e

\end{document}
```

That works as it should: the page break appears in the middle of block 'c', blocks 'd' and 'e' start on page 2, and the header therefore shows '[c/d/e]'.  That's correct.

If I uncomment the `{figure}` line, however, then the 'figure' appears on page 3, and page 2 is unchanged (page breaks within blocks 'c' and 'e'), but the header now shows '[d/d/e]'.

I am perplexed as to why this happens.  I can't find anything in `\@float` or `\@caption` which touches the marks, and in general nothing in `latex.ltx` that uses `\markboth` or `\markright` (which are the only things in `latex.ltx` which call `\mark`).   `article.cls` has a few things that call `\@mkboth`, but they're associated with `\@part`, and with lists of figures and the index.

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is possible that LaTeX typesets a paragraph in the context of one page and then moves it to another page. Similar strange things happen when one uses margin notes on a two-sided layout where sometimes a note appears on the inside margin. (I did not post this as an answer because I'm really not sure if this is the reason.)

Comment: I don't _think_ it can be that, since TeX (the program) assigns the mark quantities at the time material is put into `\box255`.  Having said that, at least some of the float placement algorithm takes place within the `\output` routine, so I can imagine something going wrong here.  Perhaps the answer is that TeX's `\mark` isn't supported within LaTeX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Answering my own question...**

The problem here is, bluntly, that LaTeX messes up the TeX `\mark` system: `\firstmark` and `\botmark` still work, but `\topmark` doesn't.  This is because LaTeX's float algorithm, which handles `\marginpar` as well as figures and tables, can invoke the output routine at times other than between pages.  That necessarily moves `\botmark` into `\topmark` in a way which means that `\topmark` is no longer the value that `\botmark` had at the end of the previous page.

LaTeX's `\markboth` system uses the TeX `\mark` system, but is specialised to the case of running section headings, and doesn't seem repurposable.

The multicol and fixltx2e packages (and the fixmarks package, which they both cite) address this problem for the case of multi-column pages, but not in a way which makes `\topmark` work in the case illustrated here.

My particular case is this: I'm setting exam papers, and want to put a [Qx cont'd] at the top of pages which start in the middle of question x.  I had beeing putting `\mark{x}` at the beginning of each question: testing `\topmark` worked fine, until the paper included figures.  I've got it working in a slightly clunky way.  I put `\mark{1x}` at the beginning of each question, and `\mark{0x}` at the end: I can then tell by looking at the number at the beginning of `\firstmark` whether I'm still in a question or not.

**Edit:** while that's a nice idea, it turns out that the a more effective solution is to save the `\botmark` manually, with `\xdef\my@topmark{\botmark}` in the page footer.  This can be examined in the following page header, where it has (exactly?) the same semantics as `\topmark`.  There might be some pathological cases where this doesn't work, but I haven't run into them.

Comment: Hah!  I didn't expect I could do that!  I notice that I don't get any reputation for that: good -- that would have been a bug.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is how to use top marks, see my package `titleps`. See also [How to add “cont.” section title to the top of pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42621/how-to-add-cont-section-title-to-the-top-of-pages) .

Comment: Thanks for this, Javier. I came across `titleps` when I recently came back to this question, and meant to edit in a pointer to it. But can you think of any case where manually saving `\botmark`, as above, wouldn't work?