# How to implement topmarks similar to titleps

Tags: header-footer

This is a follow-up question to Javier's answer on a solution for working topmarks here: [How to add “cont.” section title to the top of pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42621/how-to-add-cont-section-title-to-the-top-of-pages/)

@Javier: could you please elaborate on your idea of how you implemented topmarks in titleps? I used titleps and it does work except for two things:

- I need the literal contents of `\topshortmark\indexthumb` for use in `\int_from_alph:n { \topshortmark\indexthumb }`, for instance, but instead I get the switching mechanism with `\@namedef`. If I use etex's `\newmarks` directly, then I get the true contents but the `\topmark` is wrong.
- Also, when using the `\xspace` macro in the mark contents, `\ifsamemark` breaks with an "Undefined control sequence" error.

So I want to implement the titleps `\topmarks` without the switching mechanism.

UPDATE:

Following a hint from Javier, I tried the following setup, however, that didn't quite work yet:

```
\newmarkset{indexmark}
\newcommand{\indexthumb}{}
\newextramark{indexmark}{\indexthumb}

\NewDocumentCommand \indexsection {m} {
    \renewcommand{\indexthumb}{#1}
    \preextramark{indexmark}
    \pagebreak[2]

    \hskip 0pt plus 1fil { #1 } \hskip 0pt plus 1fil

    \extramark{indexmark}

    \fancytab{#1}{\int_from_alph:n {#1}}

    \nopagebreak\vskip\onelineskip\par\nopagebreak
}

\AddEverypageHook{
    \typeout{INT:~ \topextramarks{indexmark} \int_from_alph:n { \indexthumb } }
}
```

Comment: The basic mechanism is that explained in the TeXbook. (1) Use the "normal" extramarks, and then write `\topextramarks \int_from_alph:n { \indexthumb }` (untested). (2) It seems a bug - I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Well, no, that wasn't my question because this is LaTeX, not TeX. The output routine is what messes up the topmarks and that is why I wanted to know how you found your way around that, making topmarks possible anyway. Sadly, I also wasn't able to get (1) to work, could you please show me the exact command? I tried `\topextramarks{indexmark} \int_from_alph:n {\indexthumb}` but that is interpreted as two separate commands and gives me the current \indexthumb, not the topmark one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I did the research myself. The answer to my question is SO simple that I am wondering if I didn't pose it well enough. It suddenly struck me like lightning: if `\firstmark` works in LaTeX and `\topmark` doesn't, then one just has to keep a list of all marks, enter it at `\firstmark` and then move back one item. Or, which is equivalent, keep the predecessor of each mark in the mark itself and use that when accessing the mark with `\topmark`.

I have now read `ttlps.def` and that is exactly what it is doing. I wasn't able to fix the two problems in `titleps` that I mentioned above, so I just rewrote and minimized it the way I need it:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                           extra marks                                 %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { xxTF }

\def\ifsamemark#1#2{
    \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect

    \tl_if_eq:xxTF { #1#2 } { \firstshortmark#2 }
        { \expandafter\use_i:nn }
        { \expandafter\use_ii:nn }
}



% ttl@mkc@\a = the (macro)name for the e-tex counter for markset \a
% ttl@mks@\a = contents of a markset \a
% ttl@premks@\a = contents of the previous item of markset \a

% arg: macro, containing the current section etc.
\newcommand\newshortmark[1]{
    \newmarkset{\string#1}
    \newextramark{\string#1}#1
    \extramark{\string#1}       % initialize empty mark
}

% arg: macro or name to identify the markset
%
% \newmarkset
%    defines the ttl@mkc@#1 counter with \newmarks
%    defines \ttl@mks@#1 (to be empty)
%    defines ttl@premks@#1 to be \ttl@mks@#1
%
\newcommand\newmarkset[1]{
    % define a counter for a new markset called ttl@mkc@#1
    \expandafter\newmarks\csname ttl@mkc@#1\endcsname

    % \def \ttl@mks@#1 {}
    \@namedef{ttl@mks@#1}{}
    \@namedef{ttl@premks@#1}{\@nameuse{ttl@mks@#1}}
}

\newcommand\newextramark{\ttl@newmk@i}


% #1: markset name (macro as string: \string\macro)
% #2: \macro
\def\ttl@newmk@i#1#2{
    % def \ttl@a to be the macro name (without the \)
    \edef\ttl@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string#2}

    % call \ttl@newmk@ii {\ttl@a} {#1}
    \expandafter\ttl@newmk@ii\expandafter{\ttl@a}{#1}
}

% #1: markset name (macro as string without \)
% #2: macro as string
\def\ttl@newmk@ii#1#2{
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\ttl@a\expandafter{\@nameuse{#1}}
    \expandafter\let\csname ttl@mks@#2\endcsname\ttl@a
}



% #1: markset name
\newcommand\extramark[1]{%
    \begingroup
        \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        % the usual \mark
        \marks\csname ttl@mkc@#1\endcsname{
            {\@nameuse{ttl@mks@#1}}
            {\@nameuse{ttl@mks@#1}}
        }
        \expandafter\xdef\csname ttl@premks@#1\endcsname {\@nameuse{ttl@mks@#1}}
    \endgroup
    \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

\newcommand\preextramark[1]{%
    \begingroup
        \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        \marks\csname ttl@mkc@#1\endcsname{%
        {\csname ttl@mks@#1\endcsname}%
        {\csname ttl@premks@#1\endcsname}}%
    \endgroup
    \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

\newcommand\shortmark[1]{\extramark{\string#1}}
\newcommand\preshortmark[1]{\preextramark{\string#1}}

\newcommand\topshortmark[1]{\topextramarks{\string#1}}
\newcommand\firstshortmark[1]{\firstextramarks{\string#1}}


% #1: the markset name (or macro)
\newcommand\topextramarks[1]{
    \expandafter\use_ii:nn\firstmarks\csname ttl@mkc@#1\endcsname
}

\newcommand\firstextramarks[1]{
    \expandafter\use_i:nn\firstmarks\csname ttl@mkc@#1\endcsname
}
```

I wanted to do it completely in LaTeX3 (I love the syntax! So much easier!) but just didn't have time yet. The code can now be used like this:

```
\topshortmark\indexitem
\ifsamemark\topshortmark\indexitem{}{(continued)}
```

which will add a (continued) to the header if a list of subitems or of page numbers is broken onto a new page. I would have loved to add another mainitem to the index but really, that output routine is beyond me...

And regarding the literal contents, I can now write:

```
\AddEverypageHook{
    \tl_if_empty:xTF { \topshortmark\indexthumb }
    {}
    {
        \fancytab{ \topshortmark\indexthumb }{ \int_from_alph:n { \topshortmark\indexthumb } }
    }
}
```