# Section number of first word on the page in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using fancyhead and I wanted to include in headers number of section, which 1st word on the page belongs to:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[CE]{\thepart. \parttitle}
\fancyhead[RE]{[\thesubsection}
\fancyhead[LO]{\thesubsection]} 
\fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\begin{document}


\setcounter{page}{5}
\setcounter{part}{1}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{4}

\section{first section}

\subsection{first subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]\\
\\
that text comes from section 1 and should make header to [3.5.1
\subsection{second subsection}
that text comes from subsection 2 and changes header in the top right to [3.5.2 (supposed to be [3.5.1)
\end{document}
```

[image: xx]

Comment: Only the section number, or the section number and title? So, `0.2 second section` instead of just `0.2`.

Comment: only the section number. to be specific i need section number and subsection number but it would be similiar? i mean at 2nd page i have 2 subsections, so in header i want to have 1.1.1 (first chapter, first section, and first subsection that the first word belongs to)

Comment: Related: [How to add “cont.” section title to the top of pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42819/5764)